# "unexpected operator" in bash script ( regex )

Tags: linux, bash

There is my simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="0.jpg"

if [ $file =~ ^[0-9]+\.jpg$ ] ; then

      echo ':))))))' $file

else    

      echo ':(((( ' $file

fi
```

As you can see all is a very simple. But when i try to run it i got an error:

```
/home/sa/Desktop/regex.sh: 4: [: 0.jpg: unexpected operator
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Regex test are syntax specific to bash so must use keyword `[[` instead of `[` which is for POSIX sh compatibility

Comment: thanks for the answer. I found a way to run my script without this error. All I need for this is use [[ and run script in terminal like this: sudo bash /home/sa/Desktop/1.sh . I used "sudo bash" instead of "sudo sh".